# Why modifications on css files is not working in server rendering?

Tags: python, css, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a problem styling my html file while using SQLAlchemy library and flask framework to create a server and render html and css templates. 
All modification I make in the css file is not shown on the page. 
I suspected being mistaken in any of my code so, I downloaded a ready working project from github and it is working properly but when I modify any property even a color of an element, it is not rendered or shown on the page.

I am wondering if rendering a page using flask is problematic in responding quickly to my css modifications !

I am using python to create a database using SQLAlchemy and flask framework. 
Please talk a look at this [github-project](https://github.com/omarelewa21/ProjectTrial-) if you need a full insight.

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not come from Flask. Browsers generally use a caching system for speed and optimization purposes...

When you execute your flask code, the various static files that are rendered by the server (css, images, etc.) are cached by your browser. If you later make changes to a CSS file for example, and you restart your server, the browser will ignore the CSS file, because he knows he already keeps a copy of this file (immediately he will not understand that changes have occurred on the file). It will then be necessary that you **empty the cache of your browser** and that you restart your server, and there surprise! your CSS changes will be taken into account.